# Object referencing a lookup object field is null

Tags: apex, lookup, object

When creating the query for the field `CPQ_Sort_Decimal__c` in `Product2` the data is populated correctly (Example: 0.125). When making the following query for `SBQQ__ConfiguredSKU__r.CPQ_Sort_Decimal__c` in `SBQQ__ProductOption__c` the data does not exist and is empty. `SBQQ__ConfiguredSKU__c` is a lookup to a product2. My question is if the lookup is pointing to an object and referencing a field why is the data empty?

Comment: Could you please show us how you are querying the data?

Comment: select id, name, SBQQ__ConfiguredSKU__r.CPQ_Sort_Decimal__c from SBQQ__ProductOption__c limit 100

Comment: select id, name, CPQ_Sort_Decimal__c from product2 limit 100

Comment: @ebar instead of posting a comment, please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/239862/edit) you're question.

Answer (score 1):

In situations like yours it's very helpful to challenge your assumptions. Since your post doesn't have much information I have to make a few of my own assumptions. First, check to make sure that there actually is an ID in that field for your record.

Try the following:

```
select id, name, SBQQ__ConfiguredSKU__c, SBQQ__ConfiguredSKU__r.CPQ_Sort_Decimal__c 
from SBQQ__ProductOption__c limit 100
```

**notice the extra field, `SBQQ__ConfiguredSKU__c` as this is where the Id would be shown.**

If there is an ID, copy that Id and paste it into your URL to make sure it is actually looking at the record you think it should be. If everything checks out, verify your permissions to those objects/fields. If it still checks out, do it all again. Your query is fine, the issue is somewhere else.